# Break at address "0x1fff3f36" with no debug information available, or outside of program code

Tags: c

If i debugg or run my simple c programm with a stm32L432KCU6 with a ST link/v2 i get this error message: Break at address "0x1fff3f36" with no debug information available, or outside of program code.

PCB:
[pcb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOruk.png)

Programm:

```
#include "main.h"


void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);

int main(void)
{
  
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  
  while (1)
  {
    
  }
}
```

This is what i get if i debug:

```
STMicroelectronics ST-LINK GDB server. Version 7.0.0
Copyright (c) 2022, STMicroelectronics. All rights reserved.

Starting server with the following options:
        Persistent Mode            : Disabled
        Logging Level              : 1
        Listen Port Number         : 61234
        Status Refresh Delay       : 15s
        Verbose Mode               : Disabled
        SWD Debug                  : Enabled
        InitWhile                  : Enabled

Waiting for debugger connection...
Debugger connected
Waiting for debugger connection...
Debugger connected
Waiting for debugger connection...
      -------------------------------------------------------------------
                       STM32CubeProgrammer v2.11.0                  
      -------------------------------------------------------------------

Log output file:   C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp\STM32CubeProgrammer_a22248.log
ST-LINK SN  : 0669FF544949878667103606
ST-LINK FW  : V2J40M27
Board       : NUCLEO-F334R8
Voltage     : 0.01V
SWD freq    : 4000 KHz
Connect mode: Under Reset
Reset mode  : Hardware reset
Device ID   : 0x435
Revision ID : Rev Z
Device name : STM32L43xxx/STM32L44xxx
Flash size  : 256 KBytes
Device type : MCU
Device CPU  : Cortex-M4
BL Version  : --

Memory Programming ...
Opening and parsing file: ST-LINK_GDB_server_a22248.srec
  File          : ST-LINK_GDB_server_a22248.srec
  Size          : 5.81 KB 
  Address       : 0x08000000 

Erasing memory corresponding to segment 0:
Erasing internal memory sectors [0 2]
Download in Progress:

File download complete
Time elapsed during download operation: 00:00:00.341

Verifying ...

Download verified successfully 

Shutting down...
Exit.
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

I testes my pcb, there are no shorts and my boot0 is with a 10k ohms at gnd.

Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: try with tested board like nucleo or discovery. Shorts and boot does not guarantee that the rest is OK

Comment: the program is not the problem, I have already tested it with a nucleo and it worked.

Comment: @If program is not a problem then it is a wrong place to ask the question